# own custom module in which the value from the submitted form gives 0

Tags: forms

In a custom module, I have created a form with a text-field and a submit button.

The problem is that I can't get Drupal to save my value, and the validation function is also not called.

```
function subscription_perm() {
  return array('access subscription');
}

function subscription_menu() {
  $items = array();
  $items['generate/subscription'] = array(
    'title' => 'Subscription Form',
    'description' => 'A form to generate the subscriptions',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('subscription_gen_form'),
    'access arguments'   => array('subscription generation for the members'),
);
  return $items;
}

function subscription_gen_form() {
  $form['txtSubcription'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => 'Subscription Generation',
    '#value' => 500,
    '#size' => 10,
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['submit_button'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Click Here!'),
    '#submit' => array('subscription_gen_form_submit'),
  );
  return $form;
}

function subscription_gen_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  if($form_state['values']['txtSubscription'] < 500) {
    form_set_error('txtSubscription', t('pls enter the correct subscription amt'));
  }
}

function subscription_gen_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  db_query("INSERT INTO {Ex}(Amt) VALUES (%d)", $form_state['values']['txtSubscription']);
  drupal_set_message("the value have been submitted in the db");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation not happen due to spelling mistake in the textfield name for Subscription Generation. Please check with below one

```
$form['txtSubscription'] = array(
```

Comment: thanks a lot :D Silly mistake is not able to recognize by myself ..

Comment: welcome :) it happens sometimes

Comment: @kapil sometimes? you mean 'all the time'

Answer (score 0):

It is:

```
#default_value
```

not value that sets an initial value for a field. #value creates a form element that never displayed - similar to hidden, but not displayed in the form at all. If you just want to pass through values then #type = 'value' is what you want.

```
// Record the serial number to identify this replicant.
$form['meetingclone']['meetingclone_serial'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value',
    '#value' => _meetingclone_find_template_node()->nid . '_' . time(),
);
```